# Android ad banner using Burstly

Tags: android

I am trying to create a banner for Android using Burstly but getting the below shown errors:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.burstly.sample-2.apk]

I am not getting any errors while compilation but my application is getting crashed at run time.
Can anyone help me with this?

Following are the log errors:
05-25 11:37:06.389: I/Process(652): Sending signal. PID: 652 SIG: 9

05-25 11:41:07.719: I/ActivityThread(673): Pub com.burstly.sample.AdContentProvider: com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider

05-25 11:41:07.719: D/AndroidRuntime(673): Shutting down VM

05-25 11:41:07.779: W/dalvikvm(673): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)

05-25 11:41:07.819: I/dalvikvm(673): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4240)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3992)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3946)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4225)

05-25 11:41:07.889: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  ... 12 more

05-25 11:41:07.929: I/dalvikvm(673): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

05-25 11:41:08.290: I/dalvikvm(673): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

05-25 11:41:08.319: I/dalvikvm(673): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

05-25 11:41:08.509: I/dalvikvm(673): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

05-25 11:41:08.529: I/dalvikvm(673): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Comment: can you post the full logcat for the error?

Comment: I have posted the error logs above.

Comment: also the code that is being affected might help, especially line where you utilize the content provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem for me.

The library was not well integrated in my case. 
To solve this issue, I have created a libs folder under the application root ("BurstlySample/libs/") and added the jar file here.

Hope this helps.